# Phonegap doesnt deploy to device

Tags: cordova

I am trying to deploy phonegap app to my android device. The command "phonegap run android" returns this:

```
phonegap  detecting Android SDK environment...
phonegap  using the local environment
phonegap  compiling Android...
phonegap  successfully compiled Android app
```

But it will not deploy to my device.

"adb devices" returns my connected device.

Even "phonegap run android --device=12345" or "phonegap run android --target=12345" doenst work.

Any ideas?

Comment: is your device in development mode?

Comment: If you have Eclipse in your computer,   import your phonegap project and check if you are able to make that project run on your connected device successfully. I assume you will have the same problem over there too.  If so, something is wrong with your device's recognition.

Comment: yes, it is in dev mode. i tested a few different devices - without success...